# '__e3_' is null or not an object - google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Message: '_*e3*' is null or not an object
Line: 19
Char: 1068
Code: 0
URI: http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/6/6/main.js

I really have no clue on javascript and this is someone elses code, but does anyone know why it causes the above error in internet explorer?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Marker Animations</title>
    <link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var stockholm = new google.maps.LatLng(59.32522, 18.07002);
      var parliament = new google.maps.LatLng(59.327383, 18.06747);
      var marker;
      var map;

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function(event){
           document.getElementById("latbox").value = event.latLng.lat();
           document.getElementById("lngbox").value = event.latLng.lng();
    });

      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 13,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          center: stockholm
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                mapOptions);


        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map:map,
          draggable:true,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          position: parliament
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', toggleBounce);

      }

      function toggleBounce() {

        if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
          marker.setAnimation(null);
        } else {
          marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
          document.getElementById("latbox").value=marker.getPosition().lat();
          document.getElementById("lngbox").value=marker.getPosition().lng();
        }
      }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;">map div</div>
    Lat:<input type="text" id="latbox" name="latbox" style="width:100px;" >
    <br>
    Long:<input type="text" id="lngbox" name="lngbox" style="width:100px;" >
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you open IE's developer tools, change to the script tag, and start debugging, then when the page refreshes and the error occurs, the developer tools will show a call stack headed by your call to add a listener to the drag event of a marker, and the `__e3_` being referenced is a property of the marker, but you have not created the marker.

Move the `addListener(marker ...` call to within the `initialize()` function, after you've created the `marker`.